# sapui5 global densityAware

Tags: image, sapui5

I am looking for a global switch to tell the app that there is never desity awareness necessary.

Is there a way to stop the app globally looking for densityAware for images?

Answer (score 0):

I've never met a global switch for this.

However, you can create a global config property for your application which holds the densityAware property for the whole application.

After that, just extend the `sap.m.Image` control with your own custom control ([description](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/d12d2ee6a5454d799358d425f9e7c4db.html)) and use it in your application. In your own `CustomImage` extension, you can set the `densityAware` property of the wrapped `Image` object in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a global model all your Images' `densityAware` properties are bound to. This enables you to switch the property globally.

See the [device model tutorial](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/d63a15e5eebb45cdada317bae5f45bc2.html) for a detailed example.